# Automation of Jira and Jira Issue Updater Plugin

Tags: jenkins, automation, jira, jql

I have the following task: To automate issue converting from Resolved to Integrated if build is successfull.

I have Jira v.6 and Jenkins.

I installed Jira(wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) and Jira Issue Updater Plugin (wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin) in Jenkin

I configured this plugin(Jira Issue Updater Plugin) for needed job with task to change from Open to Resolved.

Jira SOAP URL - https://MyJiraUrl/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2
Jira Username - myusername
Jira Password - mypassword

JQL for selecting issues to be updated - project=MyProjectKeyNameFromJira and issue=MyIssueName and status= Open

Name of the workflow action to be executed - Resolved

Fail this build if JQL returns error - Checked

When I run this build I have the following error

Jira could not execute your JQL, 'project=MyProjectKeyNameFromJira  and issue=MyIssueName and status= Open': com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException:

Query validation failed: The value 'MyProjectKeyNameFromJira' does not exist for the field 'project'. An issue with key 'MyIssueName' does not exist for field 'issue'. 
Build step 'Jira Issue Updater' marked build as failure

If I try this JQL in Jira - it works.

I have Jira Standalone installation type with version 6.1

What I do incorrect?

Comment: Are you using JIRA Server or JIRA Cloud (formerly JIRA OnDemand)? And in case of the former, which JIRA Server version?

Comment: The SOAP support has been deprecated. Please use the REST version instead.

Comment: If you change the search to use matching "~" instead of the "=" on the issue, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

This means the user doesn't have permissions.  Atlassian does this on purpose to confuse hackers.  I'm not sure whether you're allowed to use expletives on this site but I'd use a whole heap to describe them for doing this.

Note: that this often means you're either doing this as an anonymous user or the user you are doing this as doesn't have permissions.  You can check the later by trying to enter the JQL in the Advanced Search while logged in as the user you want.

The first case might occur if, for example, you're using the dict options in the python jira lib.  It allows you to set the basic_auth key but doesn't use it!!! (instead you have to pass the basic_auth as a keyword argument).